# How to target a specific line of text from a list in Python

Tags: python

I'm using selenium with python2.7 and I have a css selector setup to get an element's text and its corresponding link. Im getting each users name that is on a shared account, and a link to their individual info. It prints out each name line by line, and I want to be able to reference to the persons name and use a .click() function to go to the users profile link. How would I automatically assign a class to the full element by only using the printed text? Here's my code.

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".profile_Link .profile_Name")
  for span in elem:
     print span.text
```

It will print out the list of Names like this

```
Josh Parker
Amy Doe
Parker Johns
...etc
```

I want to automatically assign a class to each element by using only their profile name. So each time i'm getting data from a complete new list of name, I can simply just look at the printed profile names and do something like this

```
  elem = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".profile_Link .profile_Name")
  for span in elem:
     print span.text

 ("Josh Parker").click()
```

and it will take me to Josh Parker's Link

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a dictionary of your classes?

```
class_dict = {span.text: MyClass( ... args ... ) for span in elem}
```

Then

```
class_dict["Josh Parker"].click()
```

Will invoke the `click` attribute of `MyClass`, as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm not sure I understand what the ( ... args ...) means. I'm getting an error message of  "Expected :)" on the first parenthesis before the ...args...

Comment: obviously you were supposed to write `MyClass` and replace `(... args ...)` with whatever arguments you wanted to pass to `MyClass`